# How to create array of bitset class objects in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, bitset

I have numbers as 10101, 1000, 11101,.... and so on. I want to store these numbers using bitset class, but dont know how to do that? Please help

Comment: Bitset class? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should use byte array instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) implementation in the standard Java SE API, you should try using that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a binary number representation to create a `BitSet`, this can be done in two steps:

- Use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) constructor that takes a string and a base as arguments.  For binary the base is 2.
- Initialize a `BitSet` from the byte array representation of the `BigInteger` by calling [BigInteger.toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) with [BitSet.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D%29).

e.g.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("10101", 2); //base 2 for binary
BitSet aBits = BitSet.valueOf(a.toByteArray());
```

`BitSet.valueOf()` is new in Java 7 so won't work in earlier Java versions.

Edit:

If you don't like initializing `BigInteger` with strings and your binary numbers fit into 64-bits, you could also use Java 7's [binary literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) and initialize the `BigInteger` using [BigInteger.valueOf(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29) method instead.

Comment: the method u specified above would work for 10101, but this is just 1 number. I have around 100 such numbers, how do I deal with them?